# How do I tell 'nuget pack' that I don't want a content folder in the package?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a nuget package from a C# project using the following command:

`nuget pack project.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release`

However when I inspect the contents of the package, it appears to have included some .tt files which causes any projects that use this dependency to fail to build unless the .tt files are removed.
[image: Nuget Package Explorer showing contents of created package]
Is there any way to tell nuget not to create a content folder or to stop these .tt files from being included?

Comment: Why did T4 templates cause build fail?

Comment: Because of some missing .ttinclude files that weren't included. The .tt files are only important to the class library itself, they don't need to be included in the package.